# Eliminate space between tikz figures

Tags: spacing

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\noindent{}\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

I know I can eliminate the white space with something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\noindent{}\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{-0.3em}
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}\\[-1pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{-0.3em}
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but this requires that i manually fine-tune the spacing and seems prone to errors. Is there an automatic way to elimate the white space (both horizontal and vertical) between the figures?

Comment: You have a "space" between the `tikzpicture` environments on the same line. If you use `...\end{tikzpicture}%` instead then the space between the environments will disappear. The space between different lines is harder and will depend on the line spacing. There probably should be a clever way of getting rid of it but a hack like `\vskip-<x>pt`  should work for an appropriate value of `x`.

Comment: The vertical space can be eliminated by setting `\lineskip=0pt`. But to isolate this setting from the rest of the document you should put this in a group and have a \par inside the group (because that's the point where it is picked up:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `tabular`, with properly set parameters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newenvironment{pics}
 {\par\raggedright % maybe \centering
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}{*{10}c}}
 {\end{tabular}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{pics}
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture} \\
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}
\end{pics}

\bigskip

\begin{pics}
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture} \\
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}
\end{pics}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The horizontal gaps are explained by Andrew's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339260/eliminate-space-between-tikz-figures#comment832242_339260): Spaces by line ends between the environments.

Since the pictures are larger than the base line skip, TeX uses the register `\lineskip` to separate boxes in vertical direction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle(1,1);\end{tikzpicture}%
\\[-\lineskip]
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]